# Silverlight Toolkit - Rating Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, silverlight, silverlight-3.0

This is my first silverlight Application.

I am trying to use Rating Control from 3.0 Toolkit with VisualStudio 2008

Here are the problems:

1. I am unable to see designer view after adding Rating Control and few other controls. I am not getting any errors or warnings on markup or while compiling.
2. Trying to access Property window for any control is giving me this message " Property Editing not available".

Is this the way silverlight was made available with Visual Studio or is there something I am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Visual studio 2008 does not support design view editing of silverlight applications.
2. Some 3rd party controls crashes the design view and simply does not show up. When this happens, property editing is not available.

Your solution:

Use [expression blend](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/blend_overview.aspx) or upgrade to visual studio 2010. Blend was made directly for interface design. Visual studio 2010 upgraded their design view for silverlight so it is now editable (still recommend blend with it)

Comment: Thank Shawn. Guess I knew these answers but just wanted to make sure...Thanks.